# If $w_1,w_2$ are unitary vector fields and there exists a parametrization $f$ such that $f_u=w_1, f_v=w_2$ then $S$ is locally isometric to the plane.

Tags: differential-geometry

Im triying to prove it.
This is an exercise of Do Carmo's Book of differential Geometry.

I try:

$<Df(e_i),Df(e_i)>=<f_u,f_u>=1$ by the hypothesis, for $i=1,2$

But $<Df(e_1),Df(e_2)>=0$ is not necessary true.

I don't know how I can continue.

But if:

$w_3=\frac{w_2-<w_1,w_2>w_1}{|w_2-<w_1,w_2>w_1|}$ then $w_3$ is a differential vector field, because $w_1, w_2$ are differential vector fields, and $<w_3,w_1>=0$.

But the EDO's thoery there exists a integral curve $\gamma$ such that:

$\gamma'_{p}=w_3(\gamma_p(t))$

$\gamma_p(0)=p$

I don't know how I can constuct a parametrization by this...

Comment: Unitary means orthonormal.

Comment: $f$ itself does the job!

Answer (score 1):

If unitary means only that the vector fields $w_1,w_2$ have unit length and not necessarily orthogonal then your manifold need not be locally isometric to the plane. Here is a counterexample. Consider the function $a$ on the plane given by $a(x,y)=x+y$. Equip $\mathbb{R}^2$ with a smooth symmetric tensor field $g$ such that the components of $g$ satisfy $g_{11}=g_{22}=1,g_{12}=a$ with respect to the standard basis of the plane. By restricting to a sufficiently small open ball centered at the origin , $g$ becomes a Riemannian metric. Take your manifold to be the open ball equipped with $g$ and take your vector fields $w_1,w_2$ to be the standard basis of the plane.  One checks easily that the sectional curvature at any point $(x,y)$ is given by $\frac{x+y}{1-(x+y)^2}$ which is obviously nonzero at points different from the origin. So our manifold (the open ball) equipped with riemannian metric $g$ is not flat.